# How to push a branch back to a private github repo

Tags: git, github

I've cloned a private repo in github to my local machine. After I'm done making some changes, I want to push the branch back to github to propose a merge  (or pull request, as github calls it).

How do I do that?

I'm absolutely new to github (I normally use bzr/launchpad, and the command was `bzr push lp:~<username>/<master-branch>/<name of the new child branch>`. What is the equivalence of this in `git`?).

[Edit: I found that my wording was confusing due to my little understanding of git's terminologies, I am going to re-describe what I did]

(`bar` is the private repo)

```
$git clone git@github.com:foo/bar.git
$cd bar
$touch <some file> # ie., make some changes
$git commit ...
$ <<<<< NOW I need to push this back to github here.
```

Comment: You mean you cloned it to your local machine, then forked a branch?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `clone` (I'm really confused with git terminology!)

Comment: In git you clone a repo, not a branch

Comment: Shouldn't it be the same thing? (ie., get a copy of the master )

Comment: @CharlesB Yeah,ok, I meant `clone a repo`. As I said, git's terminology is very confusing to me.

Comment: You get a copy of *everything* when you clone; all branches and histories. Have you only modified `master`?

Comment: @user1508893 no, when you clone a repo you get all branches, even if the `master` branch is checked out

Comment: I see. And yes, I made some changes to my local repository. How do I push it back to github? (This means it will be a branch of the master, yes?)

Comment: If you've modified master ... no; you modified master. What you really need to do is create a branch and push that, you've going to have to fix master ... sec, finding a link

Comment: @BrianRoach What do you mean "modified master"? THe private master repo is NOT owned by me (ie., I don't have the permission to push my repo back to the master repo). I think I can only push my local repo back, and request the owner to merge it to the master

Comment: Ok ... you cloned the repo, then did not branch, correct? You modified `master` locally? Or did you branch first?

Comment: Sorry if my wording was confusing (as I said, I'm not familiar with all the terminologies). Let me rephrase what I did (Editting the question now)

Comment: @BrianRoach Just edited the question, please re-read it. Thank youl.

Comment: The thing about git is that it's distributed. When you clone, you clone the repository. You now "own" it *locally*. If you didn't branch after cloning, you're modifying `master` - Posting an answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your comments above and your original question, you want to do a pull request on github but you've modified `master` locally ... that's a problem. What you wanted to do is branch first, make the changes, commit locally, and push the branch. Then you could create a pull request on github from that branch.

First what you need to do to fix that is:

> git branch mytopicbranch
>   git reset --hard origin/master

You now have a branch and have reset `master` locally to what it is in the remote repo. You can now push your branch with:

> git push origin mytopicbranch

Then on github you'll be able to create a pull request for that branch.

The normal flow would be to do the following:

```
git clone <remote repo> 
<cd to directory>
git checkout -b mybranch 
<make changes> 
<commit changes>
git push origin mybranch
<create pull request on github>
```

**Edit to add:** This is for the reason you asked; wanting to do a "pull request". If you just want to push `master` you'd simply do:

> git push origin master

And your changes will be committed to master remotely.

Comment: What is the value of `mytopicbranch`? The name of the private repo? (ie., `bar` as in my example?)

Comment: If you don't branch, there's no pull request, which is what you asked about - it will be pushed as ... master.

Comment: Sorry for asking this (supposedly very simple) question, but after I do "git clone ...", I will get a directory, then I should cd to that directory and do the checkout? Wouldn't that create another directory?

Comment: That directory contains all branches and all histories; unlike other systems you aren't checking out a branch, you're replicating the entire repository. "checkout" with git manages the revisions and the files you see in that directory are the ones currently "checked out". (don't feel bad, it took me like a week to wrap my head around git)

Comment: Ok, this makes sense now, thank you! In my head `checkout`, `clone`, and `fork` always meant the same thing, ie, to get a copy of the master repository.

Comment: No worries. If you're ever unsure about what's currently checked out in your directory, you just type `git status` and it tells you (I do this a lot, lol)

Comment: This all assumes you have rights to push to the remote (private) repository on github, of course :)

Comment: *“you've modified master locally ... that's a problem”* – Actually no, that’s not a problem. Your local branches are completely independent of your remote’s branches. It’s not a problem if they share the same name—except that it may confuse you if they serve different purposes.

Comment: @poke - it IS a problem if he meant to create a branch and doesn't want to push master back to the remote repository, which is what his original question was about. He actually doesn't *have* to reset master locally, but it will get him to a good state at the moment.

Comment: I don't want to (don't have the permission to) push my local repo directly to the private repo that I have cloned from. So yes, I think @BrianRoach is correct about what I am trying to do.

Comment: @user1508893 "Don't have the permission" as in "They person that owns it says not to"? Because otherwise that comment above where I say this assumes you have write rights comes into play ... otherwise, this whole answer really doesn't apply since you *can't* push a branch no matter what from your own PC directly to the private repo unless you have rights on github to do so.

Comment: @BrianRoach Well, the owner does NOT want changes to go into the master without review, but even when I tried `git push git@<mater>.git`, I got `error: failed to push some refs to 'git@<mater>.git` So I'd say, I cant push directly for both reasons?

Comment: You don't push like that: do a `git remote` and it'll show you the remote (should be `origin`) then you do `git push <remote> <branchname>` Although ... hmm, actually ... yeah, that should at least say "everything is up to date" if you do it the way you did

Comment: `git remote` returns the word "origin". Why? shouldn't it return something like `git@github:foo\bar.git` ? Also, what does `<branchname>` look like? Just the name? Or the full path like `git@github:foo/bar/branchname.git` ? (not to raise a 'religious' war, but `bzr` is much simpler when it comes to this!)

Comment: It's the name you gave your branch (`mytopicbranch` in the first example in my answer). `origin` is a pseudonym assigned to the remote repo you cloned from :)

Comment: So `origin`==`git@github:foo\bar.git`? Is there any way to get the 'actual' value of "origin" ? By the same token, instead of doing `git push origin mybranchname`, I could do `git push git@github:foo\bar.git mybranch name`, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And `git remote -v` will show you. (All git commands have help with `git <command> -h` FYI).  And yes, you can do that.

Comment: I see. Thank you all for the answers. They definitely help clear my head a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> The private master repo is NOT owned by me (ie., I don't have the permission to push my repo back to the master repo). I think I can only push my local repo back, and request the owner to merge it to the master

You seem to be confusing a lot things here. First of all, a repository is a single unit. When you clone a repository, you get a complete local copy of it.

If you cloned a repository, that is not owned by yourself and to which you have no write-rights, then you will not be able to push *any changes* to that repository. If that is the case, you will need to *fork* it first to your own GitHub account. To do that, click the fork button in the repository view. This will create a copy of the repository in your own account, which you will have push rights for.

So, if you have a local clone of the repository, you can do whatever you want. Nothing affects the *remote* repository, neither the original one, nor your GitHub fork. You can create as many branches as you want and commit whereever you want. Note here that branches are not some construct in Git. Branches are simple pointers to commits, so creating a branch is not doing much, and will have no impact on your structure unless you actually start committing.

If you have commits you want to push to a remote repository, you can do that by using `git push`:

```
git push <remote> <local-branch>:<remote-branch>
```

So if you want to push your local `master` branch into a branch `test` on the remote named `origin`, you can do `git push origin master:test`. As you pushed explicitely to the remote branch `test` (which does not need to exist previously), you will not touch the remote’s `master` branch. The other variations of `git push` are just abbreviations of the above command. For example `git push <remote> <branch>` which is probably the the second to most common way to push things will push your local branch `<branch>` to the tracking remote branch (usually the othe with the same name). So it’s more or less equivalent to `<branch>:<branch>`. The most common way would be just `git push` which will figure out the remote and branch on its own based on your configuration, but to be safe, you can just specify it explicitely.

So, coming back to your use case, I assume that you want to fork someone else’s repository to make a change to it and propose that change to the original author as a pull request. To do that, you should follow these steps:

- Fork the repository on GitHub
- Clone your *own* repository (i.e. the fork)
- In your now local repository do your changes
- Push the changes into your fork (any branch is fine, although using a separate one is advised for clarity)
- When browsing your fork on GitHub, click the pull request button to create one based on your pushed branch